# long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread cant seem to get rid of this

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform

i am getting the  long running Parse operation error. But i can't seem to see why.
On selecting an option this opens a view controller with all the details of the option

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Check that a new transition has been requested to the DetailViewController and prepares for it
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"TradeSend"]){

        // Capture the object (e.g. exam) the user has selected from the list
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        PFObject *object = [self.objects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        // Set destination view controller to DetailViewController to avoid the NavigationViewController in the middle (if you have it embedded into a navigation controller, if not ignore that part)
        //UINavigationController *nav = [segue destinationViewController];
        DMKDetailTradeFairViewController *detailViewController = (DMKDetailTradeFairViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        detailViewController.exam = object;
        NSLog(@"object details: %@",object);
    }
}
```

next view controller 
 get the error when this opens

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [_scroller setScrollEnabled:YES];
    [_scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 1300)];

    self.compname.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"name"];
    self.address1.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"address1"];
    self.address2.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"address2"];
    self.postcode.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"postcode"];
    self.tel.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"phone1"];
    self.email.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"email"];
    self.NewName.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"ContactName"];
    self.standnumber.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"StandNumber"];
    self.details.text = [self.exam objectForKey:@"Description"];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData];
    self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image1"] getData];
    self.image1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image3"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image2"] getData];
    self.image2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image2"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image3"] getData];
    self.image3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image1"] getData]];


    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

Thanks in Advance for your help

I have added the `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock` on 4 of them but the other 4 wont let me add it for some reason somthing about sending a void

Heres what i can do

```
[[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }];

    self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image1"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }];

    self.image1.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image1"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image2"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }];

    self.image2.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image2"] getData]];

    [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image3"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    }];

    self.image3.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"image3"] getData]];
```

Comment: When you print the object in prepareForSegue, is it all there? I'm guessing it's all of the getData calls in viewDidLoad that are causing this.

Comment: yes all data is there. and yes it is the get data but for some reason i can only solve 4 of them

Comment: All lines with getData need to be removed, and instead of doing self.Logo.image everywhere, put the right image name there. So for the line where you are getting image3 key, it should be self.image3.image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're on the right track. You should do this, though:

```
[[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
      self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
}];
```

For each image. The block returns the data in NSData format, and you are currently not using it. This way, you will use the data from the block and load all your data in the background without blocking your main thread.

Comment: ive still got 4 errors A long-running Parse operation is being executed on the main thread. X4.... its the self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: [[self.exam objectForKey:@"Logo"] getData]]; im having problems with adding the getdatainbackground

Comment: You need to remove all getData calls, and ONLY use the getDataInBackground calls.

Comment: Make sure, like in the other answer, that you check the error and that data is not nil, though, to make sure you are giving the image data and not nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:` instead of `getData` in order to avoid blocking the main thread when downloading the image data.

**EDIT :**

This is how to use `getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:`

```
[[self.exam objectForKey:@"image1"] getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
    if (error ==nil && data != nil)
        self.Logo.image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData: data];
    else
        // do something to handle the error properly
}];
```

Comment: You're UIImage must be initialized within the block, by adding getDataInBackgroundWithBlock to getData, you're not solving the issue. I've updated my answer, try it. Maybe you cannot load multiple images in background ad the same time, so you'll have to start the next download from the completion block.